# How do I setup my application under WebSphere and IBM HTTP Server

Tags: jsp, websphere-7, ibmhttpserver

I have setup WebSphere and IBM HTTP Server on a machine and I have been able to test that the HTTP Server is working. The issue comes when I try to get the portal that was given to us by the company setting up our new system. I can copy the into the htdocs directory but index.jsp files do not detect as the default document and if I click on a .jsp file to try to load it that way I get an error that it cannot find *.jsp, which is the file I just clicked on and know is there.

Any help is greatly appreciated. I have never used WebSphere before and this is completely different from IIS and Apache which I have dealt with before. I did try running the files they sent over using XAMPP with Apache and Tomcat but I got basically the same results.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be copying JSP's into the htdocs/ directory.

httpd.conf should reference a file named plugin-cfg.xml. This file is generated by the application server and describes to the WAS WebServer Plugin which requests are dynamic resources that should be proxied (forwarded to the AppServer). Part of your setup should be to generate and propogate this XML file.

Likely you get a 404 because the host aliases or context roots contained in plugin-cfg.xml don't match what's being requested, so the core of Apache/IHS tries to serve it as a static file.

I'd suggest revisiting the setup steps wrt generating or propogating plugin-cfg.xml and double-checking the paths/contents vs. what you see in yur browser.

Comment: The httpd.conf did have the link to the xml file. I am looking at plugin-cfg.xml now and it seems to mainly have the example directories listed. So I guess the main question is now how am I supposed to get it to read my content and where do I need to put my content for it to read it? The xml file shows directories but it doesn't show the path to those folders is and if I try to go through the browser (localhost:9080) I don't get anything.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your application is mapped to right IHS server(s) and appserver(s) and then you can generate the plugin-cfg.xml and propagate the new xml file(May have to do it manually). Make sure the virtual hosts are correctly setup in the httpd.conf and in WebSphere Cell.

Check application mapped to modules.
Check right virtual host and host aliases are defined.
Generate the plugin either from the console or use command GenPluginCfg.sh(bat)
and Manually copy the new xml file (Can do it from admin console also)

Comment: I have the IHS server and Websphere on the same machine. I've found the plugin-cfg.xml that is is the httpd.conf but I do not know what values need to be in there or where I need to put the files I've been given for them to be viewable.

As for your 2nd paragraph I have seen options mentioning the virtual hosts but I haven't done anything with that and I don't believe I have seen anything about mapped applications. I will look at more of the options and see if I find that anywhere.

Comment: In the WAS Admin console, Go to Applications> WebSphere enterprise application> select your application>Module>Manage Modules, here you will see to what cluster/appservers and webservers your application is mapped. Once you generate the plugin it will do all the mapping inside plugin-cfg.xml. You don't have to manually update the plugin xml file.